# Cordova firebase plugin compilation fail

Tags: android, firebase, cordova

My cordova app is very default. Since I added my first plugin : firebase, it doesn't work anymore.

My plugin list is

```
cordova-plugin-firebase 2.0.5 "Google Firebase Plugin"
cordova-plugin-firebase-lib 5.1.1 "Google Firebase Plugin"
cordova-plugin-whitelist 1.3.4 "Whitelist"
```

I believe I only need the first and last plugin, but I tried several other plugins, like AndroidX and Android X adapter.

I'm still getting the same error.

```
* What went wrong:
Failed to capture fingerprint of input files for task ':app:preDebugBuild' property 'compileManifests' during up-to-date check.
> The library com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base is being requested by various other libraries at [[17.3.0,17.3.0], [17.0.0,17.0.0]], but resolves to 17.3.0. Disable the plugin and check your dependencies tree using ./gradlew :app:dependencies.
```

I tried to modify the build.gradle from platforms\android (to by pass the version verification of com.google.android.gms but I'm getting another error.

Here is my dependencies in the build.gradle

```
dependencies {
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files

        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.0'

        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.1.0' // google-services dependency from cordova-plugin-firebase

        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.25.4' // fabric dependency from cordova-plugin-firebase
    }
```

I've seen many topic about it on git, SO or youtube, but none of them worked for me. I also tried to make new project by just typing :

1. cordova create test
2. cordova platform add android
3. cordova build (build success)
4. cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-firebase
5. cordova build (build failed)

Another interesting thing is, since I added other plugins, I can read "build success" in neon green, then the app made a standart build, then build failed. Maybe because of cordova-plugin-firebase-lib.

Many thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know the solution to this error is ... (I have encountered before and solved it this way.)

### Step 1

You need to create a file named build-extras.gradle in the root directory of the project.

### Step 2

Into the file

```
android {
     defaultConfig {
         multiDexEnabled true
     }
     {dexoptions
         javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
     }
}

dependencies {
     compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
}
```

you should add the content.

### Step 3

Finally in the root directory in config.xml

```
<platform name = "android">
+ <resource-file src = "build-extras.gradle" target = "app / build-extras.gradle" /> // You must add this
</ Platform>
```

Hope this is solved this way.

Comment: I first added the file in the root directory of my project. I had this error.

D8: Cannot fit requested classes in a single dex file (# methods: 120876 > 65536)

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug'.
> com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Error while merging dex archives:
  The number of method references in a .dex file cannot exceed 64K.

Comment: This is the same error. I tried cordova android clean but didn't help.

I feel like the changes as not been taken in account. I'm gonna try to add it somewhere else.

Comment: I added the changed directly in project\platforms\android\app\build.gradle and I have a build successful. I'm about to try.

Comment: It works, Firebase received data from my app ! Addind the plugin you recommended + adding the settings you told me in the build.gradle in the app directory was the solution. 

I can't tell you how happy I am. Many thanks to you !

Comment: I thank you. I was very happy that the problem was solved :)

Answer (score 1):

I have seen a lot of these kinds of errors in normal firebase plugins. Often errors related to version conflicts. I found the solution in a different plug.

https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-plugin-firebasex

It sets and fixes the versions for you.

Method 2 ->

Changing all google-related libraries in platforms> android> project.properties file to '+'.

for example;

```
cordova.system.library.1 = com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:+
cordova.system.library.2 = com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:+
cordova.system.library.3 = com.google.android.gms:play-services-tagmanager:+
cordova.system.library.4 = com.google.firebase:firebase-Analytics:+
cordova.system.library.5 = com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:+
cordova.system.library.6 = com.google.firebase:firebase-config:+
cordova.system.library.7 = com.google.firebase:firebase-perf:+
cordova.system.library.8 = com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:+
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I'm glad you told me about this plugin. I tried the first method, It looked very promising. I create a new project, without any plugins, added the firebasex plugin, the google-services.json from Firebase website, but I now have a new error. Maybe you had it too. I'm going to search about it.

Comment: * What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug'.
> com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Error while merging dex archives:
  The number of method references in a .dex file cannot exceed 64K.
  Learn how to resolve this issue at https://developer.android.com/tools/building/multidex.html